# Tab Automatically redirect to first tab on data change of third tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout, floating-action-button

Hi I am using Tablayout in my

**TAB1  TAB2  TAB3**

When I open the app, by default `TAB1` is selected. All the `TABs` have `recyclerview`. Now I have one `FAB` button for all the fragments. I am using `FAB` button for changing language.

Whenever user change language data will display as per language selection. Now issue is When I am on `TAB3` and changing language instead of staying on `TAB3` it goes to `TAB1`.

Can any one help me to solve this issue.

```
public class LibraryFragment extends Fragment  {

    private static final String TAG = LibraryFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private String catid;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private String SELECTED_ACTION;
    private String SELECTED_LANGUAGE,SELECTED_LANGUAGENM,sel_cat;
    private int VID_CODE;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private ArrayList<LanguageModel> langList;

    public LibraryFragment() {
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_library, container, false);

        langList = (ArrayList<LanguageModel>) getArguments().getSerializable("langlist");

        catid = getArguments().getString("frommusic");

        SELECTED_ACTION = getArguments().getString("action");

        SELECTED_LANGUAGE = getArguments().getString("sel_lang");
        SELECTED_LANGUAGENM = getArguments().getString("sel_langnm");
        sel_cat = getArguments().getString("sel_cat");
        System.out.println("in library" + SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmentPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fabChat);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setdailog();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void setdailog()
    {
        final Dialog  cpDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        cpDialog.setTitle("Select Language");
        cpDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_list);
        ListView listView = (ListView) cpDialog.findViewById(R.id.listiview_lang);
        AlertListAdapter mAdapter = new AlertListAdapter(langList, getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SELECTED_LANGUAGE = langList.get(position).getLangid();
                System.out.println("JO JO"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MusicActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("langlist",langList);
                intent.putExtra("selid",catid);
                intent.putExtra("langid",SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                intent.putExtra("langname",langList.get(position).getLangname());
                intent.putExtra("selcat",sel_cat);
                startActivity(intent);

                cpDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        cpDialog.show();
    }

    public class AlertListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<LanguageModel> mData;
        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public AlertListAdapter(ArrayList<LanguageModel> data, Context context) {
            mData = data;
            mContext = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_alert_list, null);
            }
            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_languge);

            tvTitle.setText(mData.get(position).getLangname());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
    public class CustomFragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private  final String TAG = CustomFragmentPageAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

        private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = 3;

        public CustomFragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    Fragment f1 = new SongFragment();
                    Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                    args1.putString("fromlibfrag", catid);
                    args1.putString("action", SELECTED_ACTION);
                    args1.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                    args1.putSerializable("langlist",langList);
                    f1.setArguments(args1);
                    return f1;

                case 1:
                    Fragment f2 = new PhotoFragment();
                    Bundle args2 = new Bundle();
                    args2.putString("fromlibfrag", catid);
                    args2.putString("action", SELECTED_ACTION);
                    args2.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                    args2.putSerializable("langlist",langList);
                    f2.setArguments(args2);
                    return f2;

                case 2:
                    Fragment f3 = new SmsFragment();
                    Bundle args3 = new Bundle();
                    args3.putString("fromlibfrag", catid);
                    args3.putString("action", SELECTED_ACTION);
                    args3.putString("sel_lang", SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                    args3.putSerializable("langlist",langList);
                    f3.setArguments(args3);
                    return f3;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return FRAGMENT_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return "Videos";
                case 1:
                    return "Photos";
                case 2:
                    return "SMS";

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: finish your MusicActivity activity after intent call in `setdailog()` method.

Comment: in your setdailog() method just pass the current fragment's object and pass this object in intent . . . now in your main activity just get the intent with extras and set the current fragment from intent.

Comment: @NirmalPrajapat can you help me with an answer

Comment: @Nilma I just posted an answer . .check this out

Answer (score 0):

```
int position=0; 
     tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
 @Override public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){ 
position = tab.getPosition(); 
} });

fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setdailog(position);
                }
            });
```

Now

```
 public void setdailog(int currentTab)
        {


            final Dialog  cpDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            cpDialog.setTitle("Select Language");
            cpDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_list);
            ListView listView = (ListView) cpDialog.findViewById(R.id.listiview_lang);
            AlertListAdapter mAdapter = new AlertListAdapter(langList, getActivity());
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    SELECTED_LANGUAGE = langList.get(position).getLangid();
                    System.out.println("JO JO"+SELECTED_LANGUAGE);

                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),MusicActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("langlist",langList);
                    intent.putExtra("selid",catid);
                    intent.putExtra("langid",SELECTED_LANGUAGE);
                    intent.putExtra("langname",langList.get(position).getLangname());
                    intent.putExtra("selcat",sel_cat);
                    intent.putExtra("currentTab" , currentTab);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                    cpDialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            cpDialog.show();
        }
```

Now In MusicActivity.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent  = getIntent();
    int currentTab = intent.getIntExtra("currenttab", 0);
//here you can check if you get 1, 2 or 3 in currentTab then you have to set current tab to 1, 2 or 3 respectively.
    }
```

Comment: and what is getCurrentTab ?

Comment: Yes, you're using this in a fragment

Comment: getCurrentTab() is the method of customized TabLayout, that will return the current tab count

Comment: `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
        int position = tab.getPosition();
    }
});`   use this instead of getCurrentTab()

Comment: same what?? any error or exception or something else

Comment: just check if you're getting correct currentTab count or not

Comment: i added like this because only string will not allow with that
int currentTab = intent.getIntExtra("currenttab",0);
System.out.println("TABS"+currentTab);
and i am getting 0 all the time

Comment: set a debugger at putExtra and getIntExtra and then check for the correct value

Comment: what are you getting on `onTabSelected` . . . I mean the position on tab selection . . . check with debugger

Comment: yeah! , use this `getIntExtra("currentTab", 0)`

Comment: used it and getting 0 only instead of selected tab

Comment: can you share your code only if you don't have any problem

Comment: complete code so that I can set a debugger and check what's going on